# Dockerizing PostgreSQL - psql Connection refused

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I'm playing around with Docker and I would like to Dockerize a Postgres container.

I'm following the official [example](http://docs.docker.com/examples/postgresql_service/) but I can not connect to the image running using psql.

I created the Dockerfile with the content of the example. I builded an image from the Dockerfile and assigned it a name. Then I run the PostgreSQL server container (in the foreground).

```
~/test » docker run --rm -P --name pg_test eg_postgresql                                                                                                       
2014-10-10 06:12:43 UTC LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2014-10-10 06:12:29 UTC
2014-10-10 06:12:43 UTC LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2014-10-10 06:12:43 UTC LOG:  redo starts at 0/1782F68
2014-10-10 06:12:43 UTC LOG:  record with zero length at 0/1782FA8
2014-10-10 06:12:43 UTC LOG:  redo done at 0/1782F68
2014-10-10 06:12:43 UTC LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2014-10-10 06:12:29.2487+00
2014-10-10 06:12:43 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2014-10-10 06:12:43 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

Then I open another terminal to find out the port:

```
~/test » docker ps                                                                                                                                             
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
aaedb0479139        eg_postgresql:latest   "/usr/lib/postgresql   3 days ago          Up 41 seconds       0.0.0.0:49154->5432/tcp   pg_test
```

So I can use psql to connect to the instance. But I can't...

```
~/test » psql -h localhost -p 49154 -d docker -U docker --password                                                                                             
Password for user docker:
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 49154?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 49154?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 49154?
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it work using container linking' ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I want to be able to connect from my host system.

Comment: What does `netstat | grep 49154` say ?

Comment: If you use 5433:5432 it won't expose 5433 port, and you will get connection refused. As soon as you change it to "5433:5432" it will work. Tested with the official postgres:13.2 image(13 as well).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running this on my mac worked for me:

```
 $ boot2docker ip
 The VM's Host only interface IP address is: 192.168.59.103
```

And then connect along the lines of:

```
 $ psql -h 192.168.59.103 -p 49159 -d docker -U docker --password
```

It's less than ideal to have to do this all, but the instructions at https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/ indicate it is the correct solution if you want to connect directly from you mac.

Comment: Is this maybe a network configuration issue?  I know it wasn't easy to set up the network to expose my containers to the local host's env.  My case is VirtualBox running a centos7 guest.  I needed to add a second interface to the virtual box network config and use host-only mode to join the host and guest on a second subnet.  Then I used squid to reverse proxy between the networks.  There probably is a way to do this with routes, but this seems to work fine.

Answer (score 54):

Solution for me was simply using `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` in your connection string.

https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/225

Comment: This worked for me.  (note: i am also running pgadmin on docker)

Comment: Worked for me as well, and I hadn't needed it the last time I did this same setup... I'm not sure why. However, it makes me happy that it worked!

Comment: Worked for me, running docker with WSL on Windows

Answer (score 22):

If you add the --publish option to the docker run command

```
docker run --rm -P --publish 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 --name pg_test eg_postgresql
```

when you run the docker file, then the following will work (note the port is now 5432)

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -d docker -U docker --password
```

Comment: Still happening, looks like publishing the port does not solves the issue.

Comment: Do you have a firewall that is preventing you from connecting to the port?

Answer (score 15):

To get IP address of your running container you can:

```
docker inspect pg_test | grep IPAddress
```

and then use it instead of 'localhost'.

Where pg_test is container name received from

```
docker ps
```

Comment: Or for an even cleaner output `docker inspect <container-name> | jq '.[].NetworkSettings.IPAddress'`

Answer (score 1):

Someone has answered to this question [here](https://stackanswers.net/questions/can-t-connect-docker-postgresql-9-3)

To sum up : It is not enough to publish the container's port because on OS x the docker containers are running on virtual machines.
To retrieve the "real" address of the virtual machine you should use the tool which is managing your docker daemon and containers.

I would recommand to use [docker-machine](https://github.com/docker/machine)

The logic is very similar to wf answer but instead of using boot2docker it uses docker-machine.

1-/ Retrieve the name of the virtual machine

```
docker-machine ls
```

2-/ Retrieve the IP Address of the virtual machine by using its name e.g, default

```
docker-machine ip default
```

3-/ Use this value wherever you need to specify an host value.

Comment: doesn't work with m1 machine. not sure why. It doesn't list my dockers

Answer (score 0):

This question comes up whenever you search up "postgres connection refused running on docker container" - so I wanted to show a possible solution for people that are looking on here and are using WSL.

If you are getting any issues such as

> postgres access denied | password invalid for postgres

or anything of the sort on connecting, then, while seemingly like an obvious answer, *check if the port is already being used*.

Since this answer is for WSL users, you want to check if there are any ports running on powershell / cmd prompt (running as administrator) - [link on how to do so here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199/19919302)

If there are ports running on there, make sure they are not important processes (though, if its running on 5432, that usually is only mapped to postgres, meaning you might have had postgres running on your machine before) - [then kill the process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39633428/19919302). Connections should work from here.

This troubled me for a bit before I realized I was stupid and already had set something up earlier before, but not on my linux subsystem.